# Why my GeoJsonLayer.boundingBox is equal to null?

Tags: java, android, bounding-box

I wish to center my map to my geojsonLayer.
So far I have :

```
GeoJsonLayer layer = new GeoJsonLayer(mymap,geojson);
layer.affLayerToMap();
LatLngBounds bounds = layer.getBoundingBox();
mymap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 0));
```

but the bounds is null even though the layer is set to the map

```
layer.isLayerOnMap // Return true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/geojson/GeoJsonLayer.html#getBoundingBox--) of the getBoundingBox() method (and by looking at the code), you'll see that the boundingBox has a value only when there is a FeatureCollection in your geojson (so it won't work with a simple polygon or a line). Also, It seems that it won't work at all if there is no "bbox" property in the geojson, I did not see any mecanism in the code that actually go through each coordinates and save a bounding box.

I suggest parsing the coordinates yourself using the `LatLngBounds.Builder`.